# VBA code not pulling up my form when button is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, select, initialization, range

I want to use VBA code to pull up my form. Right now the code is causing a runtime error on `Sub UserForm_Initilize()`. I  don't know a lot about VBA. I know I might need to do something like `column.selectAll` but I am not sure assume I am trying to select the first 4 columns for my form. Thanks

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub


Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: "a runtime error" is a bit vague - what specific error are you getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.